# How to determine the sine Fourier coefficients of discrete data?

Tags: fourier-transform

The following relation gives me the measurements of interest $w$ at equally distanced locations $x_j$ in space:

$$w_j=\sum_{m=1}^{11}A_m\sin\left(\frac{mπx_j}{L}\right)$$

where $A_m$ are the Fourier coefficients of sine series and $L$ the total length is physical space. I also assume $m = 1,2,...,11$.

Now, how can I obtain the coefficients $A_m$ given the data $w_j$ ?

Comment: i think this question is better suited for signal proc. SE.

Comment: You equation doesn't make sense to me.  Did you mean something more like this?

$$ w_j=\sum_{m=1}^{L}A_m\sin\frac{mπx_j}{L} $$

Also, are your $x_j$ locations uniformly spaced?

Comment: You are right. I edited my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the correction, it can now be answered.

I will assume that you have also have 11 readings.  Fewer and you are underdetermined, with more you are overdetermined.

Express your problem in matrix form.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_2 \\
w_3 \\
:   \\
w_{11} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\left(\frac{ \pi x_1}{L}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi x_1}{L}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{3 \pi x_1}{L}\right) & \dots & \sin\left(\frac{11 \pi x_1}{L}\right) \\
\sin\left(\frac{ \pi x_2}{L}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi x_2}{L}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{3 \pi x_2}{L}\right) & \dots & \sin\left(\frac{11 \pi x_2}{L}\right) \\
\sin\left(\frac{ \pi x_3}{L}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi x_3}{L}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{3 \pi x_3}{L}\right) & \dots & \sin\left(\frac{11 \pi x_3}{L}\right) \\
: & : & : & ::: & :  \\
\sin\left(\frac{ \pi x_{11}}{L}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi x_{11}}{L}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{3 \pi x_{11}}{L}\right) & \dots & \sin\left(\frac{11 \pi x_{11}}{L}\right) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 \\
A_2 \\
A_3 \\
:   \\
A_{11} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This can be seen as:

$$ W = S A $$

The solution is:

$$ A = S^{-1} W $$

This is very similar to my two answers here:

[Reconstructing a sine wave from an interval shorter than half its wavelength](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69761/reconstructing-a-sine-wave-from-an-interval-shorter-than-half-its-wavelength)

---

In the overdetermined case:

$$ W = S A $$

$$ S^T W = S^T S A $$

$$ A = (S^T S)^{-1}  S^T W  $$

This is done inside np.linalg.solve, so you just need to use that (or your platform equivalent).

Comment: This looks nice. But what if I have more than 11 readings as my case? In that case matrix manipulations are not applicable..

Comment: @DimitrisGeorgiadis If you have more readings, you are overdetermined.  In this case you will get a best fit solution.  See followup.

Comment: I get the determinant of S equal to zero. Any solutions?

Comment: @DimitrisGeorgiadis Or if the determininant of $(S^TS)^{-1}$ is zero, you are underdetermined.  You can get a solution but it won't be unique.  It is probably better to reduce your model size from 11.  Since $S$ is based on the $x_j$ values, and not your $w_J$ values, it means you don't have enough distinct domain points.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with the case of a continuous function $f(x)$ where
$$b_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^Lf(x)\sin\left(\frac{mπx}{L}\right)dx$$
I came with the following expression:
$$A_m=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n\sin\left(\frac{mπx_n}{L}\right)$$

Can anyone confirm or not that solution?